# How to desc property calculated with OData

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

```
public class Order //Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get { return OrderDetails.Sum(x => x.Amount); } set { } }
}
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Hello,

I have 2 entities as in the example. When I orderby with Odata, I cannot sort by TotalAmount. I would be very happy if you could help me on the matter.

Thank you :)

Odata Version : 7.5.14
Framework: .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to return query with projection. EF cannot look into property's getter compiled body and understand how to calculate `TotalAmount`.

```cs
return _context.Orders.Select(o => new Order
{
    Id = o.Id,
    Description = o.Description,
    OrderDetails = o.OrderDetails,
    TotalAmount = o.OrderDetails.Sum(x => x.Amount)
});
```

But better to create DTO class for such queries.